# cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char' to 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax> &'

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2008

I am getting abpve error at line `str.append(ch);` in below code.

I basically want to append str with each `char` 'ch'.

If someone know the issue please correct my error.

```
int extract(unsigned char data, char i); // Signature of extract function


void decoded(istream& input,ostream& output)
    {   
        int cnt;
        int x;

        input.read((char*)&x,sizeof(x));


        cout<<x;
        cnt=x;
        string str;
        char ch;
        for ( ; ; ) 
        {
            char c;

            input.read((char*)&c,sizeof(char));

            if ( input )
            {
                //read_bit(c,output);
                for (int i=7; i>=0; i--)
                {     
                    if(cnt)
                        {
                        cnt--;
                        ch=(char)(((int)'0')+extract(c, i));

                        str.append(ch);// I am getting error at this line.

                        if(huffmanFindTable[str])
                        {
                            output.write((char*)&(huffmanFindTable[str]),sizeof(char));
                            str.clear();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            else
            break;
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the compiler says, there is no member function with the signature

```
str.append(ch);
```

You can use either

```
str.append(1, ch);
```

or the simpler

```
str.push_back(ch);
```

Comment: first option give error "corrupt stack around str" , third option work for me.

Answer (score 1):

[string::append](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) has no member function taking a `char` as argument. You can append null-terminated `char` arrays or other `stringS`.

Comment: Now I have convert  `char ch` to `string ch` , it solve my problem. Is there any harm in above conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You can only append a "sequence" of character to a string. "append" is an operation on two (sequence) vector (take the word vector in a more generic sense) like objects.

You can do the following:

1. str.append(1, ch);
2. str+=ch;